# SharedPreferencesBackupHelper не рабочий

Tags: java, android, резервное-копирование, android-shared-preferences

Я создаю приложения, где настройки должны быть сохранены в настройках. После удаления приложения и переустановке android пользователь должен быть в состоянии продолжать использовать приложение с теми же настройками. Я нашел статью в Google[1](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html), как это сделать, но программа не работает.

Это мой манифест :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:backupAgent="TheBackupAgent"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
        android:value="AEdPqrEAAAAI89q8PXxZ5dLhRZlAq9ozTFIbpKCkQTuUkbLmUg" />
</application>
```

Это мой MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
String APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER = "counter";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


  button.setOnClickListener(this);

    SharedPreferences mSettings;
    mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    if (mSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER)) {

        String s = mSettings.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER, "");

        textView.setText(s);
    }
    else
    {
            textView.setText("empty");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(editText.getText());
    APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
    APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER = "counter";

    SharedPreferences mSettings;
    mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
    editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER, editText.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
    TheBackupAgent.requestBackup(this);
}
}
```

Это мой BackupAgent :

```
 public class TheBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper =
                new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, "mysettings");
        addHelper("AEdPqrEAAAAI89q8PXxZ5dLhRZlAq9ozTFIbpKCkQTuUkbLmUg", helper);
    }


    public static void requestBackup(Context context) {
        BackupManager bm = new BackupManager(context);
        bm.dataChanged();
    }
}
```

Для отладки я использую свой телефон (lg g3, android 5.0) по usb. 
Я устанавливаю приложение и вставляю при помощи следующих команд :

```
F:\android_s\platform-tools\adb  shell bmgr enable true
F:\android_s\platform-tools\adb  shell bmgr backup com.example.testpreferense
F:\android_s\platform-tools\adb  shell bmgr run
F:\android_s\platform-tools\adb  uninstall com.example.testpreferense
```

а потом установить снова приложение, но текст в textview уже другой, то есть не сохраняется.
Помогите мне пожалуйста :)

Comment: Данный ресурс - StackOverflow **на русском**, пожалуйста, задавайте свой вопрос на языке ресурса или используйте другой ресурс, где говорят на языке вашего вопроса.